# LyX makes mistakes rendering svg graphics

Tags: pdftex, lyx, svg, inkscape

I am writing a document in LyX 2.1.4 on Mac OS 10.11 using MacTeX-2015. I insert svg files created in Inkscape 0.91. Some of them are entirely created in Inkscape. Some are outputs from R that I imported into Inkscape from pdf and edited a bit.

What happens if I compile the document via pdflatex is the following:

- some graphics have black rectangles over the image (I think where text boxes where)
- some have a white rectangle over the image (also where the text boxes are supposed to be)
- some graphics have text boxes or other boxes inverted so that the content is a mirror image of itself

The part of the svg that originated from R usually is alright. Mainly the parts I added in Inkscape show this strange behavior. All svgs look alright if I open them in any Viewer and also if I export them to pdf directly from Inscape.

I recently had the thing with the black boxes in a poster I created in Inkscape. But now the pdf export directly from Inkscape looks alright.

I can convert all my graphics to pdf before I use them in LyX. But why does this happen anyway? Is there something wrong with my settings or packages installed?

Comment: I have never had a problem like this on Ubuntu. Can you post a minimal example in a bug report at http://www.lyx.org/trac ? Note that there are known problems with *previews* (i.e. LyX's display) but it shouldn't affect output. See e.g. http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/9778

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As PDF export from Inkscape works well, as you say, you should configure Lyx to use Inkscape as a file converter. For doing so go to `Tools > Preferences > File Handling > Converters`. Find the Converter `SVG -> PDF (graphics)`. In the field `Converter` I use the following command on a Linux system

```
inkscape --file=$$i --export-area-page --without-gui --export-pdf=$$o
```

Should be the same under OS X, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

@Deve gave the right hint

In the Inkscape wiki http://wiki.lyx.org/Tips/UseInkscapeSVGImages they state:

> as of version 2.0.0 LyX is capable of displaying SVGs without
>   configuring Inkscape as converter (i.e. without doing the procedure
>   above) but in some cases (e.g. SVG containing text, LyX running on
>   Windows), the rendering will be buggy (see
>   http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/7657). Using Inkscape as converter with
>   the procedure above solves the issues.

Apparently you don't have to add the converters manually:

> librsvg or Inkscape needs to be installed on your computer. [...] Then use Tools > Reconfigure. If you open up the Converters
>   preference again, you should see new entries there for SVG to PNG, SVG
>   to EPS, and SVG to PDF. Once you have them, everything should work
>   fine. You do NOT have to add the converters yourself; they will be
>   automatically added when LyX detects Inkscape on the path during a
>   reconfigure operation

To add the PATH to Inkscape on Mac OS they state:

> MacOS X
>
> In the Preferences under Paths you should append
>   `:/Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/Resources/bin` at the end if you
>   have Inkscape installed at the default location. (Make sure a colon
>   separates it from the other entries.) Then Save and choose
>   Tools->Reconfigure. After a restart, in the Preferences there should now
>   be listed three converters for SVG.

Now graphics look well!

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of inkscape (1.0.1), some of the options are changed , the full list of options is [here](https://inkscape.org/zh-hans/doc/inkscape-man100.html). Then the command in [Deve's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/275732/231484) should be `inkscape --export-type=pdf -C -T --export-filename=$$o $$i`

I am intented to comment this on Deve's answer, but I do not have enough repution:<